# Simulating users logged in via CAS in testng tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, testng, cas

We are writing unit tests for our java apis using [RESTEasy Server Side Mock Framework](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Server-side_Mock_Framework.html). As part of the tests, we also need to simulate user login. Some parts have to be done by user1, followed by user2 and then user1 again.

In the actual application, the login is handled via [CAS server](https://github.com/apereo/cas), ie the cas web server is available.

In the tests, we are able to mock the RESTEasy services using the mock framework. The cas login [REST api's are documented](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/casum/restful+api), but they would be part of a separate webapp and not the business webapp that involves user 1 and user 2.

How do we mock the CAS login services without having to bring up the cas server during unit testing?

If the question is not clear please let me know and I can add more details.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the pac4j project. There is an embedded CAS server that runs for a few tests.

Answer (score 0):

Your system under test (SUT) needs to be able to talk to a real CAS server or a fake one that you control. Typically this is managed by using dependency injection with a main production configuration and one or more test configurations. In your test configuration for this type of test your SUT would be configured to use a mock CAS server and your test should be able to configure said mock so that you can define how it should respond when given certain requests from the SUT.

There are other options (e.g. spinning up an embeddable CAS server or simulated one) but this moves more into an integration test than a unit test.